# How do I apply t test with different column in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I am extremely new to R (so I know I am doing something wrong). But I have 8 samples: 4 participants subjected to two treatments (control, drug) and I have multiple measurements (each a different row). Something like this:

| Measurements | A_Ctrl | B_Ctrl | C_Ctrl | D_Ctrl | A_Drug | B_Drug | C_Drug | D_Drug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 |
| Second | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 | 0.1939 |

I want to add another column that calculates the p-value for each row using a paired t-test. I would like the code to to use the column number in the code as I am considering removing a participant if their data looks different than the others as my preliminary data suggests.

I have been looking at other similar questions on stack overflow but I can't seem to get them to work. Would something in this format work?

```
df$PValue <- t.test(df[2:5],df[6:9], alternative = "two.sided", paired=TRUE)
```

where df is an Excel sheet that I imported into RStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply `t.test` for each row you can use `apply` :

```
df$PValue <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:4],x[5:8], alternative = "two.sided", paired=TRUE)$p.value)
```

Note that I have used `1:4` and `5:8` because I am ignoring the first column (`df[-1]`) in `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get p value from t test, you should use `$` symbol:

```
first_p <- t.test(df[2:5],df[6:9], alternative = "two.sided", paired=TRUE)$p.value
```